# Cannot show Modal popup extender after radgrid filter command

Tags: asp.net, telerik, ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopupextender, radgrid

I have a control that is displayed in Modal popup extender. This control contains RadGrid element. I had to create a custom filter using FilterTemplate and I get a postback call with correct command name set. However, Modal popup extender doesn't display Show() method being called.

Perhaps it is best to show it with code.

Modal popup extender on default.aspx:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pmpSetDostopIS" runat="server" Width="80%" Height="80%" ScrollBars="Vertical" CssClass="modalPopup" Style="display: none">
    <div align="center">
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="DostopIS" Font-Bold="True"></asp:Label>    
    </div>                            
    <hr />
    <asp:Button ID="btnShowPopupSetDostopIS" runat="server" Style="display: none" />
    <asp:ModalPopupExtender ID="pmpDostopISExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="btnShowPopupSetDostopIS"
        PopupControlID="pmpSetDostopIS" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" DropShadow="false">
    </asp:ModalPopupExtender>
    <uc7:ppDostopISEdit ID="ucdeDostopIS" runat="server" />
</asp:Panel>
```

ppDostopISEdit.ascx:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="rgDostopISLotusNotes" AllowMultiRowSelection="True" AllowPaging="False" AllowSorting="True" AllowAutomaticDeletes="False" 
    DataSourceID="odsLNDostop" EnableLinqExpressions="false" GridLines="None" runat="server">
    <MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowFilteringByColumn="True" TableLayout="Fixed" DataKeyNames="SLNS_ID_LN_SKUPINA" DataSourceID="odsLNDostop">
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridTemplateColumn AllowFiltering="false" UniqueName="SELECTION">
                <HeaderStyle Width="30px" />
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox id="chkbxLNAll" OnCheckedChanged="chkbxLNAll_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox id="chkbxLNSelect" Checked='<%# Bind("CHECKED") %>' OnCheckedChanged="chkbxSelect_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="NAZIV" HeaderText="Skupina" SortExpression="NAZIV" UniqueName="NAZIV" AutoPostBackOnFilter="false" CurrentFilterFunction="Contains" FilterControlWidth="200px" FilterDelay="500" ShowFilterIcon="true">
                <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
                <FilterTemplate>
                    <telerik:RadScriptBlock ID="RadScriptBlock1" runat="server">
                         <script type="text/javascript">
                             function filterLnGrid(sender, args) {
                                 var strKey = args.get_keyCode();
                                 if (strKey == "13") {
                                     var tableView = $find("<%# CType(Container, GridItem).OwnerTableView.ClientID %>");
                                     tableView.filter("NAZIV", sender.get_value(), "Contains");
                                 }
                             }
                         </script>
                     </telerik:RadScriptBlock>
                     <asp:Literal runat="server" Text="Išči"></asp:Literal>
                     <telerik:RadTextBox runat="server" Text="" ClientEvents-OnKeyPress="filterLnGrid" AutoPostBack="false"></telerik:RadTextBox>
                 </FilterTemplate>
             </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
    <ClientSettings EnableRowHoverStyle="true">
    </ClientSettings>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

ppDostopISEdit.ascx.vb (excerpt):

```
Protected Sub rgDostopISLotusNotes_ItemCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridCommandEventArgs) Handles rgDostopISLotusNotes.ItemCommand
    Call m_pmpExtender.Show()
End Sub
```

Now I am stuck, as the same thing works for a custom command on some other RadGrid.

Edit:

Further debugging showed that this is double postback problem. However, both postbacks are issued by this very same RadGrid. One is for Filter ItemCommand, the other is not, so I am assuming that it is caused by applying a filter to RadGrid.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the event bubbling is the cause for the second postback here. You most likely need to stop explicitly as shown in the SupressBubbling js method [here](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/programming/webmailgrid/defaultcs.aspx).